# Parent div is removed after .load call to populate child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I want to rotate through blog posts every 10 seconds, and refresh the content in "text-container" every 5 mins.

The issue I cannot seem to figure out is why once the load call completes, the div "main-container" gets completely removed from the page?!?

If you run the snippet, you can see main-container (black area) is there for a second, and then goes away. In my local version the inspector is showing main-container being removed from the markup.

EDIT: I noticed the embedded snippet isnt showing it the same as local and jsFiddle. [Here is a JsFiddle link showing the behavior.](https://jsfiddle.net/zyq5osct/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  reloadPosts();

  //slider
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#text-container p").css("opacity", "0");
    $("#text-container p:eq(" + i + ")").css("opacity", "1");
    if (i == $('#text-container p').length - 1) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }, 10000);
});

var timeout = setTimeout(reloadPosts, 300000);

function reloadPosts() {
  $('#text-container').load('https://www.textise.net/showText.aspx?strURL=google.com', function() {
    $(this).unwrap();
    timeout = setTimeout(reloadPosts, 300000);
  });
}
```

```css
#main-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 650px;
  top: 245px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#main-container h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#main-container img {
  position: unset;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#text-container {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#text-container p {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container">
  <h2>ANNOUNCEMENTS</h2>
  <div id="text-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you're calling `unwrap()`. That removes the parent element of `#text-container`. You just need to remove that line

Comment: facepalm!  Its always the silly simple things!